# Hide query string from url without history.replaceState

Tags: .htaccess

I want to clean my URL, for example:

> www.example.com/category/somepage/?gclid=adasdasda

or

> www.example.com/category/somepage?msclickid=adasdasda

to be

> www.example.com/category/somepage

while not loosing the `gclid` parameter.

I tried this but I'm losing my parameter in google analytics, I need to clean the URL without losing that said parameter. Google analytics cannot see the parameters.

```
if(history.replaceState) 
    history.replaceState({}, "", "/somepage/")
```

How can i remove query string from URL with `htaccess`?

Comment: Please share with us your exact failed attempts and we'll help to debug it.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy Hey, thanks for response.
This code is use now:
if(history.replaceState) history.replaceState({}, "", "/somepage/");
but i lose my parameter in google analytics, i need to clean url without losing my paramters